# Dual-boot archlinux and Windows 7 using grub-bios

Tags: grub, multi-boot, arch-linux

How can i add windows to the boot menu when using `grub-bios`. I couldn't find `menu.lst` file in my boot/grub directory. My bootloader is on `/dev/sda1`. Windows is on `/dev/sda2`, root and home are on `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5`

Comment: Is it grub 2 or 1?

Comment: @Simon
How can i check this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub#With_Windows

Assuming Windows is in `sda3` Add the following to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
# (2) Windows 7
menuentry "Windows 7" {
  set root=(hd0,3)
  chainloader (hd0,3)+1
}
```

Save and then run

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

Many distros now use grub2, which instead uses `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  However, they often recommend against manually editing this file, instead using the `update-grub` script.  If this is the case, simply installing `os-prober` should cause `update-grub` to automatically detect a Windows install and add it to the GRUB menu.

Comment: `os-prober` returns `No volume groups found`

Comment: It's likely to do that if it's looking for LVM, but it usually picks up things on non-LVM volumes as well.  Does it mention anything else?